# Powershell to be executed for Deleting Exchange Shared Mailbox email older than one month old from today's date

Tags: powershell, scripting, office365, exchange-server

I need to delete the Shared Mailbox email in the Inbox folder that is reaching about 420,000+ older than 1-month-old from today date.

> Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox")' | Search-Mailbox 'Admin@domain.com' -TargetMailbox 'HelpDesk@Domain.com' -TargetFolder 'Inbox' -SearchQuery "kind:Email AND Received:`"18/10/2018..1/1/1970`"" -DeleteContent

The script that I have found does not have the timestamp capability, and I am not sure how to modify it, so I can run this script as the scheduled task every month.

Comment: When asking questions here, please indicate what specific problem you are having. There is a danger (as this question somewhat exemplifies) that it becomes easier to ask readers to do a piece of work for you, rather than sitting down and giving it a genuine attempt first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to the below code:

```
$DT = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString("d")
Get-Mailbox | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "From:voicemail@contoso.com AND Subject:'Voicemail Message' AND received:< $DT" -TargetMailbox "helpdesk" -TargetFolder "SearchAndDeleteLog" -logonly -loglevel Full
```

For more information, please refer to the below link:

[How to Delete Emails Older than X days using Powershell](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/346481-how-to-delete-emails-older-than-x-days-using-powershell)